# How to perform validation for Onclick Javascript Custom button

Tags: javascript, validation, salesforce

I have the code below and I would like it to perform multiple field validation and give alert on each field when it is incomplete. Scenario: If I use the code without the validation and associated alerts it works 100%, when I include the validation the code goes through each step and alert and ultimately fails on the last bit to execute and flag a field as 'true' and gives error of 'Invalid or unexpected token'. Any help would be welcome

```
{
  !REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js")
}

var x;

if ('{!Case.Trigger_Submit_Spark__c}' == true || '{!Case.Spark_Service_Desk_Ref__c}' != "") {
  alert('You are unable to submit request, as this request has already been submitted to Spark')
} else {
  if ('{!Case.Spark_Service_Request_Type__c}' == "" && '{!Case.Spark_Request_Note__c}' == "") {
    alert('You are unable to submit request, as Spark Service Request Type and Request note are blank')
  } else {
    if ('{!Case.Spark_Service_Request_Type__c}' == "" && '{!Case.Spark_Request_Note__c}' != "") {
      alert('You are unable to submit request, as Spark Service Request Type is blank')
    } else {
      if ('{!Case.Spark_Service_Request_Type__c}' != "" && '{!Case.Spark_Request_Note__c}' == "") {
        alert('You are unable to submit request, as the Spark Request Note is blank')
      } else {

        if ('{!Case.Trigger_Submit_Spark__c}' == false && confirm('Do you want to submit this request?\n\nBy submitting this request the following will occur:\n 1. Case Status changed to Escalated to Tier2\n 2. Escalation Group = Spark\n 3. Email sent to Spark (Remedy)\n 4. Note placed in SalesForce chatter feed\n\nPlease check chatter feed to confirm that request has been sent') == true) {
          x = "OK";
          var c = new sforce.SObject("Case");
          c.id = '{!Case.Id}'
          c.Trigger_Submit_Spark__c = true;
          result = sforce.connection.update([c]);
          if (result[0].success === "true") {
            window.location.reload();
          } else {
            alert("An Error has occured. Error: " + result[0].errors.message);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did it enter in any if else condition?

Comment: Hi @Reshma - the script goes through the if else statements right until after the confirmation

Comment: what do you mean by failing last bit. Where it exactly it fails?